# Table - nowrap in two lines?

Tags: css, css-tables

Please take look at this code:

```
td {
    max-width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kd4zF/

I want "td" Description cell to display in 2 rows. Overflow should be hidden.
white-space: nowrap; display only one row, and without it all text is showing.
Any ideas?

Comment: please dont write **keywords** in questions, elaborate it while wrtiting

Comment: you need ellipsis on second line. right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `:before` and `:after` to td refer this http://jsfiddle.net/microbians/csYjC/

Comment: The ellipsis is shown even if the text fits in the displayed area

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
white-space:pre;
```

also press on enter where you need to break the text.

Check the following screenshot
[image]

Comment: Instead of pressing `enter`, adding `br` or a empty `div` would be better. BTW, nice answer. +1 :)

Comment: +1 great trick. I'd never thought of `pre` for multiline `ellipsis`. The only problem though, is when you resize the container. All lines are utilizing `ellipsis`.

Comment: This wouldn't **really** work. You'll just get the `ellipsis` on any line if there's no much space. It's like doing it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

`text-overflow: ellipsis` just works on single lines. That's why you have to use the `white-space` thing.

You have to make some JavaScript to achieve it. There's also a jQuery plugin: http://pvdspek.github.io/jquery.autoellipsis

There's also a little CSS trick that can fake it in multiple lines: http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css

Comment: A nice collection of possible solutions you can find here: http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/ I'm using the CSS Fade Out Way and it work's very well.